# does apache spark re-use heap memory if no caching is needed?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I was advised to set the `spark.storage.fraction` to zero if no caching is needed in my spark 2.x application. Doesn't spark know to re-use that space if no caching is done ? Should I really tell it that the caching-dedicated-space should be re-used for processing ?

Answer (score 0):

so the answer is yes, spark 2.x is re-allocating the heap space between storage and processing.